# Pass JWT Token (ID Token) when calling external System using Salesforce Connect

Tags: jwt

We are working on a Integration to get data from an external system using Salesforce Connect. The high level flow is Salesforce (Connect) -> APIGEE -> Legacy System

For Authentication - We are using Named Principal (OAuth 2.0) and authenticating using Ping IDP. The Ping IDP is configured as an Auth. Provider with Auth type of Open ID.

The issue here is that when we are completing the authentication using Ping (we get an access Token, Id Token). However when we connect to APIGEE (using Connect), the APIGEE system expects Id Token. They are only getting the Access Token in the request and they are unable to verify my request (as they expect JWT/Id Token).

Do we know that if Salesforce will pass both Access Token as well as Id Token in the request to APIGEE?